# Wait for animated button to stop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on a animated button with name `ready`. This is the source code:

http://pastebin.com/up29pSRQ

I tested this code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iwg-game-full");
        WebElement until = waitPage.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ready")));

        if (until.isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Play button is displayed");

            driver.findElementById("ready").click();
        }
```

But when I run the code I get message immediately `Play button is displayed`. How I can wait for the animation to finish?

CSS code for animation:

```
.popIn .animating {
    animation: 0.5s ease 0s normal both 1 running popIn;
    filter: blur(0px);
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    will-change: transform;
}
@keyframes popIn {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.1);
}
50% {
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
}

.popIn:nth-child(1) .animating {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.popIn:nth-child(2) .animating {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.popIn:nth-child(3) .animating {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Does this ready button become invisible after animation finish??

Comment: No, it's just hidden and disabled before it's displayed.

Comment: You mean this becomes hidden and disabled after finishing animation. Right??

Comment: No, the button is disabled and hidden during the animation. After that it's visible.

Comment: Is there a change in the class attribute of this button or any other attribute after animation is over?

Comment: i think u can use element size instead of isDisplayed(). try this: 
bool cont = true;
do
{
   element = driver.findElement(By.id("ready"));
  if(element.size > 0){
    cont = false;   
}


}while(cont);

Comment: make sure the id is unique and let me know... i will convert it to answer

Comment: I tested this: http://pastebin.com/dpKPmgrv ButI get timeout.

Comment: ok can you pls print the element size at hidden status and visible status by system.printout()?pls do me this favor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use a custom condition to wait for the targeted element to become displayed and steady. The element could be considered steady if its position remains the same between two calls.

Here is an example:

```java
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
  .until(steadinessOfElementLocated(By.id("ready")));
```

```java
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> steadinessOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {

        private WebElement _element = null;
        private Point _location = null;

        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            if(_element == null) {
                try {
                    _element = driver.findElement(locator);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            try {
                if(_element.isDisplayed()){
                    Point location = _element.getLocation();
                    if(location.equals(_location) && isOnTop(_element)) {
                        return _element;
                    }
                    _location = location;
                }
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                _element = null;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "steadiness of element located by " + locator;
        }
    };
}
```

```java
public static boolean isOnTop(WebElement element) {
    WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)element).getWrappedDriver();

    return (boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
        "var elm = arguments[0];" +
        "var doc = elm.ownerDocument || document;" +
        "var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();" +
        "return elm === doc.elementFromPoint(rect.left + (rect.width / 2), rect.top + (rect.height / 2));"
        , element);
}
```

Comment: I get   basicScreenResizeTest(org.selenium.google.MonopolyLinesWellcomeWindowResizeTest): unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (463, 566). Other element would receive the click: <span></span>

Comment: You could also wait for the element be to be on top. See updated answer.

Comment: Having come across this as the only solution that works, I have extended it slightly in my case, to scroll if needed `elm.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();`. Don't scroll if you don't need to because you might scroll the element underneath e.g. a slightly badly configured header ;). BTW future readers may want to switch to Playwright or similar immediately

Comment: And also this `return elm === foundElement || elm.contains(foundElement);`

Answer (score 0):

Code in the pastebin has `is-visible pulsing` as a class of the button and in the CSS code for animation (mentioned above) has class name `popIn .animating`

It seems like class name for button is getting changed from `popIn .animating` to `is-visible...` once animation is finished.

If that is the case you can use explicit wait to get the attribute change. Try something like below, it should work.

```
webdriver.wait().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'popIn .animating')]")));
```

Comment: I get void cannot be dereferenced. wait is void

Comment: It was an example, you may need t change the xpath accordingly.

Comment: I used this WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 35);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'popIn .animating')]"))).click();   But again it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that that animation is "played" using jQuery so you can do:

```
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
```

If you cast it to a `Boolean`, you just need to add a timeout to wait for it to become `true`.

You can even achieve this using `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
    public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I get illegal start of expression

Comment: Try it now, I forgot to update the lambda expression to be Java friendly.

Comment: I get ')' expected. Do you know where I Need to add )?

Comment: Language syntax is killing me. Try it now.

Comment: I need to use import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutor;?  I get no suitable method found for until(<anonymous java.util.function.Predicate<WebDriver>>)
    method FluentWait.until(com.google.common.base.Predicate<WebDriver>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous java.util.function.Predicate<WebDriver>> cannot be converted to com.google.common.base.Predicate<WebDriver>)
    method FluentWait.<V>until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) V
        (argument mismatch

Comment: The package should be `org.openqa.selenium`.
Try this import: `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;`
And you can check more here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: @Cosmin, the animation is executed by the CSS engine, not JQuery. Moreover, `jQuery.active` returns the count of pending requests, which is not related to the animation state.

Comment: As I said, I was unsure about who is rendering the animation in his application. And yes, `jQuery.active` returns the count of pending requests, that's why I'm returning a boolean the wait method. To actually wait for the number of requests to be 0. This also includes the animations executed by jQuery.

Comment: @Cosmin, have a look at the source, `jQuery.active` doesn't include the animations. To handle the animations with JQuery, you need to check `jQuery.timers`.